# Form validation fails but still submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, validation

I have the following JS code:

```
function checkFull(id) {
    var input = $('#' + id).val();  
    if (input == "") {
        return false;   
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkSame(id1,id2) {
    var input1 = $('#' + id1).val();    
    var input2 = $('#' + id2).val();
    if (input1 == input2) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
function showErrors() {
    if (!checkFull('username')) {
        $('#userfield').show(); 
    }
    else {
        $('#userfield').hide(); 
    }

    if (!checkFull('email')) {
        $('#notsame').show();   
    }
    else {
        $('#notsame').hide();   
    }

    if (!checkFull('confemail')) {
        $('#notsame2').show();  
    }
    else {
        $('#notsame2').hide();  
    }

    if (!checkFull('espncode')) {
        $('#nocode').show();    
    }
    else {
        $('#nocode').hide();    
    }

    if (notSame('email','confemail')) {
        $('#notsame2').show();
        $('#notsame').show();   
    }
    else {
        $('#notsame2').hide();  
        $('#notsame').hide();
    }
}
function valform() {
    showErrors();
    if (checkFull('username') && checkFull('email') && checkFull('confemail') && checkSame('email','confemail') && checkFull('espncode')) {
        form.submit();
        alert('success');
    }
    else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

And the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="forms/post.asp" onsubmit="valform();return false">
            <strong>Poker Username</strong> <span id="userfield" style="display:none;color:#F00">*</span><br />
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" style="width:230px;" />
            <br /><br />
            <div class="vert">
                <strong>Email Address</strong> <span id="notsame" style="display:none;color:#F00">*</span><br />
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="width:230px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="vert2">
                <strong>Confirm Email Address</strong> <span id="notsame2" style="display:none;color:#F00">*</span><br />
                <input type="text" name="confemail" id="confemail" style="width:230px;" />
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="espn">
                <div class="txt"><strong>Enter the ESPN special code</strong></div>
                <input type="text" name="espncode" id="espncode" style="width:230px;" />
            </div>
            <div id="nocode" style="display:none">
                You need to enter the code above
            </div>
            <div class="tc">
                <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" /> <strong>You agree to the terms and conditions of this sweepstake. Only one entry per person per sweepstake period. Any additional entries will be disqualified.</strong>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="submit">
                <input type="image" src="submit_BTN.png" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Even if I leave the form blank, when I press submit it will go through. Why is that?

Comment: is there any of your validation working?

Comment: @pKs - yes the 'errors' that i'm showing when running ``showErrors()`` are being displayed for a split second and then the form submits

Comment: Your first two functions could be greatly reduced to [this](https://gist.github.com/c6945009d34c9e1842c7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the value from your validate function inside the `submit` handler:

```
onsubmit="valform();return false"
```

should be:

```
onsubmit="return valform();"
```

Whenever `valform` returns false this will prevent the form from submitting.

By the way, the `form.submit()` call inside your `valform` function makes no sense. It will be submitted anyway if the function does not return false.

```
if (/*validity checks pass*/) {
    alert('success');
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

But, looking through your code [with this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UZ8HE/) I noticed there is an error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: notSame

If you fix the name of your function it will work. You should use the developer tools available to you to debug such minor bugs. There's Firebug for Firefox and Chrome/Safari come with a web inspector right built in. Opera has Dragonfly too.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this just now and it still submits the form.. Any ideas?

Comment: The error is then probably in your validation. Are you sure that it does what you intend it to do?

Comment: I removed the ``form.submit()`` from the part that should be executed when the form is validated and just left an ``alert("success");`` there. When I submit the form, I don't get the alert but the form still submits, so from what i gather it does return false, but still submits the form..

Comment: Also, if I remove the ``showErrors()`` from the ``valform`` function, it does work by not submitting the form if validation fails. So this is happening because I have the ``showErrors()`` function included in the ``valform`` function for some reason.. any ideas?

Comment: You got it in your last edit, the fact that i tried to use ``notSame()`` which didn't exist caused the issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possible cause:

- `onsubmit="valform();return false"` change to `onsubmit="valform();"` in the form.

try if still not works then tell.